# Load a Geoserver's shape File into Openlayers to add in other layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openlayers-3

I want a good advice on the mapping with openlayers. I have a shape file save in the geoserver which i can even display by the use of openlayer link in GeoServer.

What I want to do is called that shape file in my HTML,CSS,JavaScript page of the openlayer so that I can add other layers or draw on top of the layer that I called from the Geoserver and save the modifications.

I want your ideas on how I am going to do this because I am very new in openlayers a small example will be useful for me

Answer (score 5):

When you work with GeoServer and OpenLayers you don't actually work with shapefiles. You load shapefile in GeoServer once and then all interaction is going through WMS/WFS protocols. You can also modify layer features via WFS-T.

See [GeoServer example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html) with getting feature info

Comment: this should be the correct answer t this vague question. congrats @sergey kolosov

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example in the official website of OL3 [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html)

you'll have to put your html and js files ( all your web project ) in the folder data_dir/www/ under your geoserver folder, unless you have something else in mind